# How to "Add this data to the data model?" and make data in values distinct?

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, distinct

I am using Excel 2016, and I have the code to create a `PivotTable` from my data set. However, I'm not sure how to include the data in the data model (which is an option you see when clicking on "PivotTable" from the Insert Tab.

My goal is to have a Distinct Count of my variable that I'm using in the Values data field.

```
With PvtTbl.PivotFields("sid")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Function = xlSum
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    .Position = 1
```

I tried replacing `"xlSum"` with `"xlDistinct"` but of course that would be too easy haha.

Comment: what are you trying to do with this code ?is it not working ? are you getting an error ? if yes, which line ?

Comment: @ShaiRado This was just part of the code to make my pivot table.  What I want to do is change the function to go from Sum to Distinct.  In order to do this I have to "add the data to the data model." I'm not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Please note that vba coding with data model pivot is totally different than pivot sourced by normal data range, You may use such below code after empty the data field:

```
    With PvtTbl
    .AddDataField .CubeFields("[Measures].[Distinct Count of sid]"), "Distinct Count of sid"
    End With
```